# What is the Azure "api.cds.appsplatform.us" service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-business-central

I am developing a multi-tenant application to use Microsoft's Business Central API.  At first I want to check if I can simply log in myself.

However, every time I try to grant admin consent inside the app's API permissions, I get this error:

> This app requires access to a service (\"https://*.api.cds.appsplatform.us/\") that your organization is not subscribed to or has not enabled.

I cannot find anything online about "api.cds.appsplatform.us".  I have a subscription (trial) set up, I also have a trial subscription with Business Central (although removing all the API permissions to just the default Microsoft Graph permission, still gives me the same error).

The error message is sort of unhelpful, so what do I need to enable to access my own app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only API permissions I needed for a Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central app was "Dynamics 365 Business Central" and its subpermissions.

I had included "Dynamics CRM" as an API permission, which requires CDS (Common Data Service), hence the error above.

However, when I wrote above that I had attempted to remove the above permissions and tried the 'grant admin consent' button again, and I got the error again, the problem was that I had forgotten to refresh the page *after* I had removed the "Dynamics CRM" permission.

Indeed, the takeaway from the error is that one has added a permission too many.  But every time one removes a permission, it is paramount that one refreshes the page before attempting the 'grant admin consent' button again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the CDS here is Common Data Service. Common Data Service for Apps is a service built on the Common Data model that you can use to store, build, and manage apps and app data. It's used most by PowerApps and Microsoft Flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-intro

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april19/dynamics365-business-central/

Comment: OK, but how do I activate CDS for my organisation?  I thought that would come with the Business Central trial subscription the account has.  Although, I cannot see that I have Business Central trial subscription from within Azure, it only occurs when I log into Business Central.

Comment: I believe the AAD app needs all dedicated permissions added for PowerApps Runtime Service and Windows Azure Service Management API.

Comment: Adding those API permissions changes the error, when I click 'grant admin consent': `This app requires access to a service (\"http://rts.powerapps.com\") that your organization is not subscribed to or has not enabled.`

Comment: I figured it out, I had to remove permissions and then *refresh* the page.  Then it finally realised I did not need those services after all.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Do you mind sharing your solution and marking it as the answer? I think it might be helpful to others facing this error.